# Пара вопросов начинающего администратора Asterisk

Tags: asterisk

Повесили тут на меня IP-телефонию на основе Asterisk, потихоньку изучаю эту штуку, но есть практические задачи, которые желательно решить не дожидаясь досконального изучения теории. Вот, например, 2 задачи:

1. консоль rasterisk имеет такую команду как "sip show peers", которая показывает список пиров, при этом если линк до пира поднят, то в поле Host отображается его IP, если упал, то - Unspecified. Интересует информация по упавшим пирам, можно ли как-то узнать какой IP был у него до падения. Нужно для понимания структуры сети телефонии.
2. есть абонент, при звонках к которому при занятой линии идут длинные гудки вместо коротких. Это неправильно. Как это исправить?